# How do I output, in C++, all links from a saved .html file that are in the <a href> tags?

Tags: html, c++, regex, parsing, hyperlink

Currently writing a program that, given a URL, will save a copy of the page's HTML in a .txt file, and then attempt to parse that .txt files for hyperlinks that are in the  tags. Example:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com">Visit example.com!</a>
```

Right now, everything except the parser works. I output the contents of the html file to a .txt. I then convert it into a string, and then attempt to parse that string using regex, and store all the hyperlinks in a vector. I think print out the contents of that vector. The code for the parsing section of my code is as follows:

```
vector<string> extract_hyperlinks(string html_file_name )
{
    static const regex hl_regex( "<a href=\"(.*?)\">", regex_constants::icase ) ;

    const string text = file_to_string(html_file_name) ;

    sregex_token_iterator begin( text.begin(), text.end(), hl_regex, 1 );
    sregex_token_iterator end ;
    return vector<string>( begin, end ) ;
}
```

The parser is not putting anything into the vector, even though the string is populated with the .txt file converted into a string, which clearly contains values such as `<a href="http://www.example.com">Visit example.com!</a>`.

What am I doing wrong and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
vector<string> extract_hyperlinks(string html_file_name )
{
    static const regex hl_regex( "<a href=\"(.*?)\">", regex_constants::icase );
    const string text = file_to_string(html_file_name) ;

    std::vector<std::string> ret_vec;
    std::copy( std::sregex_token_iterator(text.begin(), text.end(), hl_regex, 1),
              std::sregex_token_iterator(),
              std::back_inserter(ret_vec));
    return ret_vec;
}
```

Comment: That would work if html was always well formed. Unfortunately most html pages you find on the web have tons of error. You should find an html parsing library that already takes this into account.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, Regular expressions are either so simple that they are inadequate or so complex that they are incomprehensible

As per the advice of Martin York, you really need a HTML parsing library.

I would advise using goolge's gumbo-parser at https://github.com/google/gumbo-parser. It is a well-tested pure C99 library and has some C++ example files. The find_links.cc example file does what I think you want.